# Why the error "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display" appears when Qt test is executed?

Tags: c++, linux, docker, qt, circleci

With CircleCI, when a Qt test is executed on a Debian docker image, I get the following error :

```
********* Start testing of TestGuiApplication *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.7.1, Qt 5.7.1 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 6.3.0 20170516)
PASS   : TestGuiApplication::initTestCase()
QFATAL : TestGuiApplication::testConstructor() QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
FAIL!  : TestGuiApplication::testConstructor() Received a fatal error.
   Loc: [Unknown file(0)]
Totals: 1 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted, 3ms
********* Finished testing of TestGuiApplication ********
```

The problem also is that error doesn't appear systematically. Could you help me please ? Thank you.

Comment: can you share your circleci config?

Comment: Yes, of course. Here's my CircleCI configuration : [.circleci/config.yml](https://github.com/SPlesskin/genepy/blob/develop/.circleci/config.yml). Thanks for your help.